# Can't switch to repl in spacemacs cider (Clojure)

Tags: emacs, clojure, spacemacs, cider

In spacemacs, I am able to start a cider repl with `cider-jack-in`: it says 'Connected.' followed by a quote, as expected. But then `cider-switch-to-repl-buffer` does not open a repl buffer, and just produces the following message:

`Invalid function: (repl (or the-repl a-repl))`

Googling 'cider "invalid function repl"' produces only a cider issue relating to nim-mode (https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/1712), which is not one of the configuration layers I have installed.

I am able to run the repl from the terminal using `lein repl` without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following 'solution' while trying to debug this issue. I have no idea why it works and it's not very satisfying, but it does seem to resolve the problem.

1. In spacemacs, activate debug mode with `SPC t D`
2. Try to switch to repl buffer with `SPC m s s`
3. In the debug frame, hit `ENTER` over `(repl (or the-repl a-repl))` to open `cider-mode.el`.
4. Make any edit to `cider-mode.el` and save.
5. Undo the edit just made and save.
6. Restart spacemacs.

After doing this, `SPC m '` (`cider-jack-in`) followed by `SPC m s s` (`cider-switch-to-repl-buffer`) opens the repl buffer as desired.